# Multiple models in one controller vs Many partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I was just curious, what is considered to be better?
Multiple models into one Controller - ie, a Controller performing business access on many models and then passing those results to a view, OR

One model per controller, with many partial views, and with Controller actions linking the controllers together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A controller may use MANY models.

yet a view can have only 1 model passed into it which is called ViewModel.

So maybe you can say, 1 Output ViewModel Per ActionResult, yet as you mentioned within the action result, you may use4 many models and the result will boil down to the Output ViewModel

the model that goes to the partialview, may be exact same as the model for the parent view or a child object of the model of the parent view.

Comment: Its possible to pass in a ViewData[] dictionary to your view, filled with multiple models. Granted, this is passing one whole object, but allows for the flexibility of accessing multiple models per view.

Comment: yes, but it is a sloppy way. you have to create a viewmodel of all the models you need on the view. thats the right way of doing it

Comment: I agree using ViewData[] is not best practice, but hey it's there

Comment: yes. thats for special scenarios. I personally use it very rarely and like you said I dont find it best practice. an idea would be a senario when you return a page back but has error which the error is not part of the viewmodel, so you may pass that using viewdata